# Filter matched elements by class name in Angular js.

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Problem:**

I have an unordered list of items which are returned from a json call and are output using ng-repeat. Each one of these items has a class name (there are about 9 categories).

I have a second unordered list which is simply a list of available categories.

**Aim:**

I want to be able to select one of the categories in the right hand list, which will apply a filter to the actual list of returned elements. This should be activated via a toggle (so click once: filtered, click again: filter removed). So it is simply looking to match the classname in the clicked element, to the elements that share the same classname in the list of json data.

I cannot use ng-model (as this is reserved for certain form elements).

For my jsfiddle I am simply using static html.

Here is my angular code:

```
/* angular custom filter on returned ajax api data */
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('main', function($scope) {
    $scope.chFilters = {};

    $scope.links = [
        {name: 'atm'},
        {name: 'internet'},
        {name: 'mobile'},
        {name: 'sms'},
        {name: 'postal'}
    ];

    $scope.channels = ["ATM", "INTERNET", "SMS", "POSTAL","MOBILE"];

});
```

(this is based on another question I found on SO). Unfortunately the fiddle is a bit messy and has some extraneous code in it.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="main">
        <ul>
            <li class="atm">Some stuff ATM</li>
            <li class="internet">Some stuff INTERNET</li>   
            <li class="sms">Some stuff ATM</li>   
            <li class="atm">Some stuff ATM</li>   
            <li class="postal">Some stuff POSTAL</li>   
            <li class="atm">Some stuff ATM</li>   
            <li class="internet">Some stuff INTERNET</li>   
            <li class="postal">Some stuff POSTAL</li>   
            <li class="postal">Some stuff POSTAL</li>   
            <li class="atm">Some stuff ATM</li>   
            <li class="sms">Some stuff SMS</li>   
            <li class="mobile">Some stuff MOBILE</li>   
            <li class="internet">Some stuff INTERNET</li>   
            <li class="mobile">Some stuff MOBILE</li>   
        </ul>

        <ul class="channel-filters">
            <li ng-repeat="link in links | filter:chFilters" class="{{link.name | lowercase}}"><a ng-click="chFilters.name = link.name">{{link.name | uppercase}}</a></li>
            <li class="last" ng-click="chFilters.name = ''">CLEAR FILTER</li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="channel in channels | filter:chFilters">
                <strong>{{channel}}</strong>
                <a ng-click="chFilters = channel">{{channel}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- original -->
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="link in links | filter:chFilters">
                <strong>{{link.name}}</strong>
                <a ng-click="chFilters.name = link.name">{{link.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the actual HTML from the application (with the call to the api).

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li class="search-text-channel">
        <input type="textarea" ng-model="searchTextChannel.$" placeholder="Search"/>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="day in interactions.model.byDay | filter:searchTextChannel" ng-click="hidden = !hidden" ng-init="hidden = false" class="{{day.channel | removeSpace | lowercase}}" ng-class="{'closed': !hidden, 'open': hidden}">
        <span class="date">{{day.date}}</span>
        <span class="subheading">{{day.channel}}</span>
        <ul ng-show="hidden">
            <li ng-repeat="interaction in day.interactions">
                {{interaction.time}} {{interaction.description | removeUnderscore}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="load-more">
        <a href="" ng-click="interactions.loadMore()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>LOAD MORE</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have managed to recreate this functionality in jquery, but I think it would be better to implement an angular solution in an angular application.

I've tried researching and also attempted to implement show/hide as well as a custom filter, but so far no joy.

Here is my (messy) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/7cft0e43/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="channel in channels | filter:chFilters.name">
        <strong>{{channel}}</strong>
        <a ng-click="chFilters = channel">{{channel}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- original -->
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="link in links | filter:chFilters.name">
        <strong>{{link.name}}</strong>
        <a ng-click="chFilters.name = link.name">{{link.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Update [Plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/singhmohancs/7cft0e43/6/)

Let me know if you have any question on this.

Comment: OK, but I need the filter to apply to the top list of elements.  <ul>
            <li class="atm">Some stuff ATM</li>
            <li class="internet">Some stuff INTERNET</li>   etc

Answer (score 0):

Here is part of the solution:

Suppose your items look like this:

```
$scope.items = [
    { class: "atm", label: "Some stuff ATM" },
    { class: "internet", label: "Some stuff INTERNET" },
    { class: "sms", label: "Some stuff SMS" },
    { class: "postal", label: "Some stuff POSTAL" },
    ...
];
```

To show a filtered list (only filtering by a single channel for now): create a separate list in the scope, with the filters applied:

```
$scope.click = function(name) {
    $scope.chFilters.name = name;
    $scope.filteredItems = $scope.items.filter(function(item) {
        return item.class === $scope.chFilters.name;
    });
};
```

Call this click handler from the bottom list:

```
...<a ng-click="click(link.name)">{{link.name | uppercase}}</a>....
```

And show `filteredItems` in the top list:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in filteredItems" ng-class="item.class">{{item.label}}</li>
</ul>
```

So this is really just a starting point, it should be extended to handle multiple filters, etc...